# Python set error reporting level like in PHP

Tags: php, python, warnings

How can I set error reporting and warning outputs in Python like in PHP `error_reporting(E_LEVEL)`?

Comment: Why do you want this? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: error_reporting **is not** responsible for outputs! but for level only. and it should be always at max. just don't touch it not in PHP nor in Python

Comment: I could be wrong, but the OP is asking for the Python equivalent to PHP's `error_reporting`.

Comment: @Gordon in PHP this feature has very limited use. To deal with dirty legacy code only. I doubt it have any good use for Python either.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel well, doubting is not knowing ;) especially if you dont even know if an equivalent exists at all.

Comment: The reason I'm calling for external python script using commands module and it gives one response FAIL or SUCCESS but due to some warnings which were fired during it's execution I've a garbage content I don't need.

Comment: @Gordon yes I'm asking about error_reporting equivalent, great!

Comment: Is there any equivalent to PHP's ob_clean function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vaguely related option might be the setting of level in the [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module of the Python standard library, and I quote from Python's docs:

```
import logging
LOG_FILENAME = 'example.log'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
```

That `level=` determines which logging messages are emitted and which ones are filtered.  However this only applies to errors (and other messages) emitted through `logging` module functions, **not** to (e.g) tracebacks resulting from exceptions; if you want to control the latter (what kinds of message come out when the process dies by propagating an exception), you can build something based on [sys.excepthook](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook), but your degrees of freedom will still be somewhat limited (in particular, after the reporting -- abundant or scarce as it may be -- the process *will* exit if an exception has propagated to that point).